# Dates on CV: Ending of studies vs Date of award

Tags: resume, education

Due to thesis correction times and other standard administrative matters, the date between my effective ending of academic duties (i.e. the thesis discussion day) and the date in which the award was notified to me differ by a month and a half.

In the CVs I have sent out I have put the date of award as it is the only ending date I have on an official document (although it is nothing more than a university page, the official document has yet to come).

I was pretty happy with such choice and had no doubts. However, having listed my thesis supervisor as reference, I am a bit concerned of the fact that the dates he can communicates (ending of thesis work) and the date on my CV may not add up.

Is this a false problem? Should I stick with what I have and then explain it in case this comes up in an interview? Or should I put the day on which I ended my actual studies?

Comment: I only bother listing things in months on my resume.  `May 2010 - June 2014`, for example.  Nicely smooths over little timing issues like you describe.  Is that approach an option for you?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Nope. I did use months, but in these terms there is a two-months discrepancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date on the CV/resume should be the date that will be on the diploma/ official transcript. If they decide to ask for a copy or an official transcript that is the date they will see.

If there is a gap of several months and you are in that gap, then you could mention that the work has been completed but the actual certificate hasn't been presented. For example some universities only have two ceremonies a year (May and December) if you finish during the summer session, you will have to wait until the December ceremony. Of course the last class might have been in June. So note on your resume that you have completed your course work, and update it when you receive the Diploma.

Answer (score 1):

The CV's meant to get your foot in the door. Personally I put the month of award once its completed (and leave out the dates when it was in progress) , but you could always put May 2010 - June 2014 (Awarded Aug 2014).

When the exact details matter, you probably will already be interviewing, and can clear minor stuff like that easily. No one's going to bother if you're a *little* off, especially where such delays are standard

Comment: I would tend to agree.  Even after completing all the course work you were still working thorugh the administrative side of getting your degree which I would tend to count as still working to earning the degree.  The first and last week of most jobs I have had have been administrative tasks but I still consider my self employed by the company for that time even though im not "working" (in my case coding).